# WooCommerce wrap custom checkout fields in a div

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-checkout-fields

Hi to all in my plugin I added custom fields to WooCommerce checkout:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'my_custom_billing_fields', 10, 1);

function my_custom_billing_fields($fields) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_checkbox'] = array(
        'type'     => 'checkbox',
        'label'    => __('I would like to receive an invoice', 'myplugin'),
        'class'    => array('form-row-wide', 'my_custom_billing_cb'),
        'priority' => 25,
        'clear'    => true
     );
     $fields['billing']['billing_fiscalcode'] = array(
            'type'       => 'text',
            'placeholder' => __('Codice fiscale', 'myplugin'),
            'label'      => __('Codice fiscale', 'myplugin'),
            'class'      => array('form-row-wide', 'inv_create_elecinvoice'),  
            'priority'   => 30,
            'clear'      => true
         );

    $fields['billing']['billing_vatcode'] = array(
            'type'       => 'text',
            'placeholder' => __('Partita Iva / VAT', 'myplugin'),
            'label'      => __('Partita Iva / VAT', 'myplugin'),
            'class'      => array('form-row-wide'),
            'priority'   => 31,
            'clear'      => true,
        );
     // [...] more fields added  
     return $fields;
}
```

The checkbox behaviour should be similar to this element:

```
<input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1">
```

by ticking/unticking this I may show/hide shipping fields. I noticed that these fields are wrapped in a div

How may I do anything similar for my custom checkout fields?

I tried to use this as a guideline: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309700/how-to-hook-on-a-woocommerce-checkout-field/309788 without success

I hope I was clear enough in explaining
Thanks